# Finding part of string in windows bash

Tags: bash, git, shell, githooks

I need to add the task code from the branch name to every commit. We figured out that this should be done with a hook.

Here's the code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Include any branches for which you wish to disable this script
if [ -z "$BRANCHES_TO_SKIP" ]; then
BRANCHES_TO_SKIP=(master develop)
fi
# Get the current branch name and check if it is excluded
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
BRANCH_EXCLUDED=$(printf "%s\n" "${BRANCHES_TO_SKIP[@]}" | grep -c "^$BRANCH_NAME$")
# Trim it down to get the parts we're interested in
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -e 's:\([a-z]\+\/\)*\([A-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\).\+:\2:')
# If it isn't excluded, preprend the trimmed branch identifier to the given message
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] &&  ! [[ $BRANCH_EXCLUDED -eq 1 ]]; then
sed -i.bak -e "1s,^,$TRIMMED: ," $1
fi
```

Right now what's happening is this:

> LG-132: LG-132: LG-132: LG-132: LG-132: LG-132: LG-132: Merge branch 'develop' of https://git.dw.com/scm/lg/webapp into develop

So the branch code gets added every time I do an amend. Now, I am trying to check if the branch code is included in the commit message, and if so just break/return 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Include any branches for which you wish to disable this script
if [ -z "$BRANCHES_TO_SKIP" ]; then
  BRANCHES_TO_SKIP=(master develop)
fi
# Get the current branch name and check if it is excluded
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
BRANCH_EXCLUDED=$(printf "%s\n" "${BRANCHES_TO_SKIP[@]}" | grep -c "^$BRANCH_NAME$")
# Trim it down to get the parts we're interested in
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -e 's:\([a-z]\+\/\)*\([A-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\).\+:\2:')
# If it isn't excluded, preprend the trimmed branch identifier to the given message
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] && ! [[ $BRANCH_EXCLUDED -eq 1 ]]; then
  set BRANCH_NAME|find "$TRIMMED" >nul && shouldAddCode=true || shouldAddCode=false
  if $shouldAddCode; then
    echo "test"
  else
    sed -i.bak -e "1s,^,$TRIMMED: ," "$1"
  fi
fi
```

I am getting this in the console:

> find: ‘LG-132’: No such file or directory

Now this code just doesn't work. I was using this code as reference:

```
set "i=hello world"
set i|find "world" >nul && set test=yes || set test=no
echo %test%
pause
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it ended up being a bit chaotic, but this is what I came up with

```
#!/bin/bash
# Include any branches for which you wish to disable this script
if [ -z "$BRANCHES_TO_SKIP" ]; then
  BRANCHES_TO_SKIP=(master develop)
fi
# Get the current branch name and check if it is excluded
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
BRANCH_EXCLUDED=$(printf "%s\n" "${BRANCHES_TO_SKIP[@]}" | grep -c "^$BRANCH_NAME$")
# Trim it down to get the parts we're interested in
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -e 's:\([a-zA-Z]\+\/\)*\([a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9]\+\).\+:\2:')
TRIMMED=${TRIMMED^^}
# If it isn't excluded, preprend the trimmed branch identifier to the given message
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] && ! [[ $BRANCH_EXCLUDED -eq 1 ]]; then
  COMMIT_MESSAGE="$(cat "$1" | sed -E "s,^#.*|$TRIMMED: *,,g")"
  echo "$COMMIT_MESSAGE" >"$1"
  sed -i.bak -e "1s,^,$TRIMMED: ," "$1"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reference  does not look like bash code, but like a CMD script.

To check in a bash script whether some variable begins with a particular string, the canonical way is to as `case`...`esac` construct, for example:

```
case "$BRANCHNAME" in
"$TRIMMED"*)
  # yes, it's there
  echo "test"
  ;;
*)
  # no, it's not there; add it
  if ! [[ $BRANCH_EXCLUDED -eq 1 ]]; then
    sed -i.bak -e "1s,^,$TRIMMED: ," "$1"
  fi
  ;;
esac
```

Note the weird case arm syntax, which has just the closing parenthesis after the pattern and ends with a double-semicolon.

Comment: Don't take my code example literally. Do your own debugging. My answer just tells you the programming pattern that you should use, i.e., `case`...`esac` and pattern matching instead of some weirdo form of `set`, `find` and pipelines.